# In PowerShell, how can I extract a file from HKEY_Users from all SIDs?

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am writing a PowerShell module to look for data that each user who has logged onto the computer at some point might have in their directory in HKEY_USERS. My initial thought was to mount HKEY_USERS, find a way to store each user's SID in a string variable, and then loop through all folders like so:

`dir HKU\<STRING VARIABLE HOLDING SID>\Software\MyApp\Mydesireddata`

Is there a way I can avoid having to loop through SIDs (because I won't know them ahead of time), and extract that file info from each SID on the system while remembering which SID it came from?

EDIT: Here is an example of the key I'm trying to extract from each user's SID using regedit (vncviewer's EulaAccepted)

[image]

Comment: This question makes no sense. There are no files in the registry.

Comment: There is data I am trying to extract from each directory in HKEY_USERS. If you mount HKEY_USERS, you can access that data from PowerShell.

Comment: The registry key name is literally `mydesiredfile.txt`? Can you maybe post a screenshot of a sample registry key in `regedit`?

Comment: No, it's session data for a piece of software the user might or might not have installed. I just gave it an arbitrary name. I've added a screenshot.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to iterate through computers in active directory and run this script locally to see if each user that appears in HKEY_USERS has certain software installed that may or may not have stored values. The VNC example I provided is identical to my needs.

Comment: But why do you need to do it? What problem are you solving by doing all of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Get-ChildItem` to retrieve each user-specific subkey:

```
$UserHives = Get-ChildItem Registry::HKEY_USERS\ |Where-Object {$_.Name -match '^HKEY_USERS\\S-1-5-21-[\d\-]+$'}
```

Then loop over each entry and retrieve the desired registry value:

```
foreach($Hive in $UserHives)
{
    # Construct path from base key
    $Path = Join-Path $Hive.PSPath "SOFTWARE\MyApp\DataKey"

    # Attempt to retrieve Item property
    $Item = Get-ItemProperty -Path $Path -Name ValueName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    # Check if item property was there or not    
    if($Item)
    {
        $Item.ValueName
    }
    else 
    {
        # doesn't exist
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. This seems to work as I intended. Before I accept as the answer, is there a way I can do this without a loop for efficiency purposes? I am looking for the same ItemProperty in all SID folders, so I am curious if I can do one traversal when at the level of these SID folders' parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

I tackled this issue a slightly different way; preferring to make use of a conspicuously placed wildcard.

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKEY_USERS\*\SOFTWARE\TestVNC\viewer\ -Name EulaAccepted | 
   Select-Object -Property @{n="SID";e={$_.PSPath.Split('::')[-1].Split('\')[1]}},EulaAccepted
```

The wildcard will automatically check all available paths and return what you need as well as the SID from the parent path.

As for the username (which is probably more useful than a SID), you didn't specifically ask for it, but I added it in for grins; this should cover local and domain accounts.

*mind the line breaks*

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKEY_USERS\*\SOFTWARE\TestVNC\viewer\ -Name EulaAccepted | 
   Select-Object -Property @{n="SID";e={$_.PSPath.Split('::')[-1].Split('\')[1]}},EulaAccepted | 
   Select-Object -Property @{n="User";e={[System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new($_.SID).`
     Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value}},SID,EulaAccepted
```

Getting the username is just ugly; there's likely a cleaner way to get it, but that's what I have in my head.  The double-select really makes my skin crawl - there's something unpleasant about it.  I could just do a one shot thing, but then it gets so unwieldly you don't even know what you're doing by looking at it.
I've included a screenshot of the registry below, and a screenshot of the screen output from running the few lines.

[image: redacted view of the registry for one user]

[image: redacted screen output of running the above; mind the line breaks]